# Simply function F and find alpha for which F will be min

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, optimization

I have point coordinates like `[x, y]`, where `x` and `y` are positive natural numbers. I need to find such '$\alpha$' for which `F` is minimum.

$ F = \frac{x^2\cos^2\alpha + y^2\sin^2\alpha}{\cos \alpha  \sin \alpha}$

*Question:* how to simplify the function above and find '$\alpha$' for which `F` is minimun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2\cos^2\alpha+y^2\sin^2\alpha=F\cos\alpha\sin\alpha$$

Divide both sides by $\cos^2\alpha,$ to get $$y^2\tan^2\alpha-F\tan\alpha+x^2=0$$

As $\alpha$ is real, so will be $\tan^2\alpha\implies$ the discriminant must be $\ge0$

$\implies F^2\ge4x^2y^2\implies$ either $F\ge2xy$ or $F\le-2xy$

which is also discernable by the fact $$F\pm2xy=\frac{(x\cos\alpha\pm y\sin\alpha)^2}{\cos\alpha\sin\alpha}$$

Comment: so how to determine alpha?

Comment: @user3676933, $F$ can have minimum value if $F\not<0$  For $F\ge0,$ the minimum value $(=2xy)$ occurs if $(y\tan\alpha-x)^2=0$

Comment: got it. great thanks!